# console.log is not working in Android 2.1 emulator

Tags: android, console, android-emulator, javascript

I'm running one web application...  in an Android emulator browser.  In one javascript file I'm trying to output some string as:

`console.log("android");`

But I didn't got this log using adb logcat.

I even tried to start adb logcat firstly and then tun the app, but didn't get a log message 
which I used in `console.log`

Is there any way I can get my log message?

Answer (score 1):

There is some info about this on the nitobi/phonegap blog:

http://blogs.nitobi.com/joe/2010/02/26/console-log-on-android-webview/

Answer (score -1):

I don't think Android's browser supports `console.log`, nor do I believe it is possible to write to logcat from within the browser.

Comment: is there any other way....    ?

i have to get some text from js  and thats to big enough so i can't just type them seeing alerts...

Comment: You could try opening a new window and writing to it: `window.open("", "").document.write("example")`

Comment: Android does indeed have console.log, see http://www.nanaze.com/2009/01/debugging-javascript-on-android.html for instance